# how to add the current date to time column in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a table which hold only time part.

```
  TIME 
 08:00
 08:00
 08:00
 08:00
 18:00
 19:00
 20:00
```

Now, i need to concatenate the time with current date. for that i tried with below code.

```
to_date( to_char (sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')|| Time,'HH24MI')
```

but that is not working as expected and getting the below error

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

Can you please help me to solve this problem.
Expected output(date time format):

```
14-Feb-23 08:00
14-Feb-23 09:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What datatype do you expect as result? A string?

```
SQL> with test (time) as
  2    (select '08:00' from dual)
  3  select to_char(sysdate, 'dd-Mon-yy ') || time as result
  4  from test;

RESULT
---------------
14-Feb-23 08:00
```

---

If you expect date, then

```
SQL> with test (time) as
  2    (select '08:00' from dual)
  3  select to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'dd-Mon-yy ') || time, 'dd-Mon-yy hh24:mi') as result
  4  from test;

RESULT
--------
14.02.23
```

Hm, what format is that?! My default! Modify it to something else, e.g. what you said you want but - nonetheless - value previous code returns *is* a valid date value:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd-Mon-yy hh24:mi';

Session altered.

SQL> with test (time) as
  2    (select '08:00' from dual)
  3  select to_date(to_char(sysdate, 'dd-Mon-yy ') || time, 'dd-Mon-yy hh24:mi') as result
  4  from test;

RESULT
---------------
14-Feb-23 08:00

SQL>
```

Comment: expected datatype is date time.

Answer (score 0):

You have time strings like `'08:00'`. And you have `to_date( to_char (sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')|| Time,'HH24MI')`.

The expression `to_char (sysdate,'YYYYMMDD')|| Time` results in something like `'2023021408:00'`.

You want to convert this result string into a datetime (that Oracle inappropriately calls `DATE`) with `TO_DATE`: `to_date('2023021408:00', 'HH24MI')`.

You do notice, that the string you have constructed and the format you are using don't match? Your string's format is not `'HH24MI'`, but `'YYYYMMDDHH24:MI'`.

Hence use:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YYYYMMDD') || time, 'YYYYMMDDHH24:MI')
```